# Swap charactors in string

Tags: python

hi I want to write a function to swap 2 charactors in a string. for instance, if input swap('12345',2,3), the return result shall be '13245'
i wrote below function, but i got error msg says"'int' object is not subscriptable", why is that?

```
def swap(x,a,b):
        tempa = x[a]
        tempb = x[b]
        i=0
        listx = list(x)
        while i<len(listx):
            if i==a:
                listx[a] = tempb
            elif i==b:
                listx[b] = tempa
            i=i+1
        return listx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in the following way:

```
In [1]: def swap(some_character, a, b):
  ....:     some_list = list(some_character)
  ....:     some_list[a-1], some_list[b-1] = some_list[b-1], some_list[a-1] # subtracted -1 to refer to their actual indexes
  ....:     return ''.join(some_list) # prepare new string 
  ....:

In [2]: swap('12345', 2,3)
Out[2]: '13245'

In [3]: swap('abcdefg', 3,5)
Out[3]: 'abedcfg'
```

Comment: I tried your code, it gave another error msg:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
so i edit it to be 
def wap(some_character, a, b):
 some_list = list(str(some_character))
 some_list[a-1], some_list[b-1] = some_list[b-1], some_list[a-1] # subtracted -1 to refer to their actual indexes
 return float(''.join(some_list)) # prepare new string

Comment: It would appear, then, that your problem is that you're calling it as `swap(12345,2,3)` instead of `swap("12345",2,3)` - without the quotes, you're passing an int, not a string.

Comment: @Jasmine Are you sure you are not giving a number as the input for  `some_character`?

Comment: @RahulGupta Yes, i did input some number as the input for some_character. I see your point!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your're asking why does your code doesn't work, or if you want to find a better swap function, but at any rate, here's a better swap function:

```
def swap(s, a, b):
    return s[:a-1] + s[b-1] + s[a:b-1] + s[a-1] + s[b:]
```

The idea is that each string has two swapped characters, which divide the string into beginning, middle, and end substrings. This function just concatenates the swapped letters and the substrings.

The code you give (and Rahul Gupta's) runs without an error. The difference between your function and the two in the answers is that our functions return a string and use 0-based indices, while yours returns a list and uses 1-based indices.